# How to set up PyAMF Django gateway so it uses AMF3?

Tags: django, amf, pyamf

How to set up PyAMF Django gateway so it uses AMF3 instead of the default AMF0?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default PyAMF supports both AMF0 (NetConnection remoting) and AMF3 (Flex messaging) of which RemoteObject is one flavour.

The docs give a [simple example](http://docs.pyamf.org/dev/tutorials/general/helloworld/flex.html) of how to approach a PyAMF gateway with both.

Also, you can set pyamf.DEFAULT_ENCODING = pyamf.AMF3 :-)